# Eclipse “Open Call Hierarchy” across the whole working set/workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, call-hierarchy

Is there a way to extend the “Open Call Hierarchy” function to the whole working set or workspace? (i.e. across multiple projects)
This would be very handy when searching for deprecated methods and dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried to "misuse" the "search for text" method? That will give you false positives but at least it is a start...

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing currently, but it's cumbersome (dialog) and, as you already mentioned, gives false positives. Also it misses the hierarchy

Comment: By default *Open Call Hierarchy* searches in workspace. Click on down arrow in view to see *search in...* and *search scope* options.

Comment: Ah, the scope was wrong. If you turn the comment into an answer, i'll happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `Open Call Hierarchy` searches in workspace. Click on down arrow in `Call Hierarchy` view to see `Search In...` and `Search Scope` options.

Guide to find *down arrow*:

In the `Call Hierarchy` view window from the right there are `Maximize`, `Minimize` and `View Menu`. `View Menu` is represented by a triangle pointing down and that is what you need to click.

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru: From the right `Maximize`, `Minimize` and `View Menu`. `View Menu` is represented by a triangle pointing down.